# Unable to find a <servlet-name> element which map

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have inherited a huge home-grown MVC Java web app running under Glassfish and am trying to add a new servlet to it but getting error

> "Unable to find a `<servlet-name>` element which map: `/VSDHosts/app/LegacyBulkLookup`"

in the `server.log` file.  I don't understand why it can't find it since it seems like I'm doing it exactly like existing servlets and my `web.xml` has

```xml
<servlet-name>LegacyBulkLookup</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/WEB-INF/legacy/legacyBulkLookup.jsp</jsp-file>
```

and

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AppController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In AppController.class there is a method called `processRequest`.  It is basically one huge if/else if clause.  One of those handles `legacyBulkLookup` like this:

```java
} else if (resource.equals("LegacyBulkLookup") ) {
                forwardToo = resource;
```

At the end there is another if statement which presumably sends all the session data collected to the view (legacyBulkLookup.jsp) which I created:

```java
dispatcher = context.getNamedDispatcher(forwardToo);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

But the view doesn't get displayed.  Just shows a web page that says

```
"Internal server error.
The server encountered an internal error and cannot proceed."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *"Internal server error"* just basically means an exception was being thrown. Find it and its stack trace in server log. It represents the answer to your problem.

Comment: [#|2015-08-04T22:46:35.791-0600|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-5181-2;|Unable to find a <servlet-name> element which map: /VSDHosts/app/LegacyBulkLookup|#]

Answer (score 0):

For the legacy servlet you should have in your `web.xml` file something like this:

```xml
<servlet>
<servlet-name>LegacyBulkLookup</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/WEB-INF/legacy/legacyBulkLookup.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>LegacyBulkLookup</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/LegacyBulkLookup/*<url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: first line probably should have <servlet> on it? copy-paste error?

Comment: @kg_sYy yes, added `<servlet>` to open a tag.

Comment: My understanding is that the <servlet-mapping> stuff is handled by the AppController class as the form action that calls it ends with /app/LegacyBulkLookup.  There is another form button action that ends with app/LegacyLookupSearch and that is handled by AppController (no <servlet-mapping> either) and that works just fine.  I'm modeling it after that one.

Comment: Servlet mapping is per servlet config. If you have another sevlet with it's own mapping than you should use a dispatcher to forward request to another servlet.

Comment: I believe that's what I'm doing